# Why unbounded above activation function is important for training

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, bounds, activation-function

One of the desirable properties of activation functions is to be unbounded above and bounded below. I guess part of the reasons why it should be unbounded above is to avoid vanishing gradient problems and avoid saturation, which could cause a fixed update in the gradient, that could slow down the training.

Could you also give other reasons why we need the activation function to be bounded below (what is wrong with having negative gradients) and why it should be bounded above?

Comment: can you link to where you read or heard this?

Comment: I found it in "Mish: A Self Regularized Non-Monotonic Activation Function," paper. This is my understanding though. So please correct me if I am wrong.